# OpenXML: Difference of using Element.Val and Element{ Val = "Val" }

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

Basically, this

```
pRp.GetFirstChild<ParagraphStyleId>().Val = "Heading1";
```

and this

```
pRp.GetFirstChild<ParagraphStyleId>().Remove();
                    pRp.InsertAt(new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Heading1" }, 0);
```

is giving me different results. The latter one works as expected. The first one doesn't. Why?

What I am trying to do is setting the first paragraph of the document to a style of Heading1, whether or not ParagraphStyleId is present, or if another style has been set.

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to understand the complete scenario you need to understand the diference between reference types and value types. Only C# 7.0 and later versions supports returning ref types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns

In the first scenario:

```
pRp.GetFirstChild<ParagraphStyleId>()
```

The function GetFirstChild needs to return a reference in order for the modifications of the val property changes the pRp object. Remember that the default behavior returns a shallow copy of the desired object. So any changes you make is apply to the copy and not the parent object.

In the second case:

```
pRp.GetFirstChild<ParagraphStyleId>().Remove();
```

This line operates directly on the parent object, this is why is capable of removing the object.

```
pRp.InsertAt(new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Heading1" }, 0);
```

And finally in here you are operating once again on the parent instance by appending a new object into it.

The main difference is that in the first case you are operating on a copy of the ParagraphStyleId object and in the second you are working directly on the parent instance which is pRp.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!